# c++: LNK2019 and 1120 errors in tic tac toe game

Tags: c++

So I was trying to make a tic tac toe game but I've been getting an errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl check(char * const,bool)" (?check@@YAXQAD_N@Z) referenced in function _main    tictac
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl WriteTable(char * const)" (?WriteTable@@YAXQAD@Z) referenced in function _main tictac
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  tictac
>   I hope anyone of you can help me.
>   code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void check(char t[], bool end);
void WriteTable(char t[]);
void playerX(char t[]);
void playerO(char t[]);

int main() {
bool turn = true;
char t[9] = "";
bool end = false;
do {
    WriteTable(t);
    if (turn == true) {
        playerX(t);
        turn = false;
    }
    else {
        playerO(t);
        turn = true;
    }

    check(t, end);
} while (end == false);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void izpis(char t[]) {
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cout << t[i] << " ";
    if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
}

void playerX(char t[]) {
int a;
cout << "playerX: ";
do {
    cin >> a;
    if (t[a - 1] == 0) {
        t[a - 1] = 'X';
    }
} while (t[a - 1] != 'X');
}

void playerO(char t[]) {
int a;
cout << "playerO: ";
do {
    cin >> a;
    if (t[a - 1] == 0) {
        t[a - 1] = 'O';
    }
} while (t[a - 1] != 'O');
}

void check(int t[], bool end) {

bool equal = false;

if (t[0] == 'X' || t[1] == 'X' || t[2] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[3] == 'X' || t[4] == 'X' || t[5] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[6] == 'X' || t[7] == 'X' || t[8] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[0] == 'X' || t[3] == 'X' || t[6] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[1] == 'X' || t[4] == 'X' || t[7] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[2] == 'X' || t[5] == 'X' || t[8] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[0] == 'X' || t[3] == 'X' || t[8] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}
else if (t[6] == 'X' || t[4] == 'X' || t[2] == 'X') {
    cout << "X won" << endl;
    end = true;
}



if (t[0] == 'O' || t[1] == 'O' || t[2] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[3] == 'O' || t[4] == 'O' || t[5] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[6] == 'O' || t[7] == 'O' || t[8] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[0] == 'O' || t[3] == 'O' || t[6] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[1] == 'O' || t[4] == 'O' || t[7] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[2] == 'O' || t[5] == 'O' || t[8] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[0] == 'O' || t[3] == 'O' || t[8] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}
else if (t[6] == 'O' || t[4] == 'O' || t[2] == 'O') {
    cout << "O won" << endl;
    end = true;

}

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (t[i] != 'X' && t[i] != 'O') {

        break;
    }
}

if (equal == false) {
    cout << "draw";
    end = true;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see WriteTable() implemented. For check you changed the function signature from `void check(char t[], bool end);` to `void check(int t[], bool end) {`

Comment: Your prototypes must actually match the functions you implement, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems here:

```
void WriteTable(char t[]);
```

This function is declared but never defined. How do you plan on using it?

```
void check(char t[], bool end);
```

And:

```
void check(int t[], bool end) {
```

Do these signatures match to you? The problem should be fairly obvious now.